# O `WebBrowser` usa como base algum navegador nativo do windows?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou vendo que da pra usar um `WebBrowser` no Form do C# mas queria saber se ele é como um `iFrame` que usa o próprio navegador para criar essa janela de navegação.

Minha duvida é se ele usa o Edge ou algo do tipo pra criar esse `WebBrowser`.

Cada negador teu seu modo de interpretar o código, por exemplo no Google Chrome ele usa o `webkit` qual o `WebBrowser` usaria ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O controlo `WebBrowser` de `WinForms` utiliza por omissão a versão **7** do IE, mas isso pode ser contrariado alterando um valor no `Registry`: [Internet Feature Controls (B..C)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)#browser_emulation)

Se no seu código pretender utilizar sempre a última versão disponível no SO, pode implementar a classe abaixo (disponível no **SOen**: [Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)):

```
public class WebBrowserHelper
{
    public static int GetEmbVersion()
    {
        int ieVer = GetBrowserVersion();

        if (ieVer > 9)
            return ieVer * 1000 + 1;

        if (ieVer > 7)
            return ieVer * 1111;

        return 7000;
    } // End Function GetEmbVersion

    public static void FixBrowserVersion()
    {
        string appName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        FixBrowserVersion(appName);
    }

    public static void FixBrowserVersion(string appName)
    {
        FixBrowserVersion(appName, GetEmbVersion());
    } // End Sub FixBrowserVersion

    // FixBrowserVersion("<YourAppName>", 9000);
    public static void FixBrowserVersion(string appName, int ieVer)
    {
        FixBrowserVersion_Internal("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", appName + ".exe", ieVer);
        FixBrowserVersion_Internal("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", appName + ".exe", ieVer);
        FixBrowserVersion_Internal("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", appName + ".vshost.exe", ieVer);
        FixBrowserVersion_Internal("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", appName + ".vshost.exe", ieVer);
    } // End Sub FixBrowserVersion 

    private static void FixBrowserVersion_Internal(string root, string appName, int ieVer)
    {
        try
        {
            //For 64 bit Machine 
            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(root + @"\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", appName, ieVer);
            else  //For 32 bit Machine 
                Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(root + @"\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", appName, ieVer);


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // some config will hit access rights exceptions
            // this is why we try with both LOCAL_MACHINE and CURRENT_USER
        }
    } // End Sub FixBrowserVersion_Internal 

    public static int GetBrowserVersion()
    {
        // string strKeyPath = @"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer";
        string strKeyPath = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer";
        string[] ls = new string[] { "svcVersion", "svcUpdateVersion", "Version", "W2kVersion" };

        int maxVer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ls.Length; ++i)
        {
            object objVal = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(strKeyPath, ls[i], "0");
            string strVal = System.Convert.ToString(objVal);
            if (strVal != null)
            {
                int iPos = strVal.IndexOf('.');
                if (iPos > 0)
                    strVal = strVal.Substring(0, iPos);

                int res = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(strVal, out res))
                    maxVer = Math.Max(maxVer, res);
            } // End if (strVal != null)

        } // Next i

        return maxVer;
    } // End Function GetBrowserVersion 
}
```

**Utilização**

```
WebBrowserHelper.FixBrowserVersion();
WebBrowserHelper.FixBrowserVersion("SomeAppName");
WebBrowserHelper.FixBrowserVersion("SomeAppName",intIeVer);
```

Comment: Não tem como fugir do IE ? usar um chrome ou outro navegador ?

Comment: Com esse controlo não, terá mesmo de se "contentar" com o IE. Mas dê uma olhada aqui, pode ser que ajude! [Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)